# Splitting a method across two files in C#

Tags: c#, methods, partial

Is it possible to split a method across two files in C#? I know partial methods are there, but they seemingly cannot do this.

Here's the scenario. I'm using an open-source library and need to add some customizations in one or more files. For example, I want to add two new fields to the class `Employee` and then initialize them in the `InitializeFields()` method of that class. Since the open-source project continues to evolve and new versions are released every now and then, I want to keep my customizations separate from the original project, to easily upgrade to newer versions of the library.

I have already split all the required classes into `Orig.cs` and `Custom.cs` using `partial class` syntax, and have added my custom fields in `Custom.cs`. Now the problem is that I have no way of splitting the `InitializeFields()` method, so that my custom code goes into `Custom.cs` file.

Please note that I cannot use inheritance to solve the problem. The open-source library would contain numerous references to Employee class and I cannot afford to change all of them.

Comment: Generally speaking, this is *not* a maintainable way of extending existing code. Have you considered inheriting from the `Employee` class and adding your own fields? This way you can override `InitializeFields()`, init your own fields, then call `base.InitializeFields()`.

Comment: I am sorry why can't you use inheritance ? cause there is alot to change ? does find and replace resolve this ?

Comment: _would contain numerous references to Employee class and I cannot afford to change all of them_ - take a look at __Refactor, Rename__

Comment: **Have you considered contributing your modifications to the open source project itself?** It's likely that somebody else would benefit from your work not to mention that compatibility becomes maintained by the community itself. If the full scope of your changes can't be incorporated into the open source library (IE: Your code is proprietary or the project doesn't accept your contribution) then you may consider making a contribution to the library that simply facilitates your ability to extend the employee class. This may be as simple as implementing the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.o

Comment: @Avner & Micah: See David's answer below.

Comment: @Micah & Henk: The lib is getting upgraded relatively quickly. I don't want to spend time every 2nd or 3rd day doing find and replace.

Comment: @Chris: I'm constantly in touch with the community and original authors and have been contributing to it. Thanks anyway, it is an important thing for the developers to remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this, you're compiling the library yourself, right?

I understand you don't want to subclass `Employee`, because then all the library code that does `new Employee()` won't work. However, what if you rename `Employee` to `EmployeeBase` in Orig.cs, and provide the class `Employee` in Custom.cs? That way when the library code is compiled, `new Employee()` will reference your class, not the library one. Since you're compiling the library and your customizations in the same project, you can make this substitution.

Comment: Thanks David. Clever use of OOP.